# Display coordinates in X decimal places

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.7

I want to use ArcPy (for ArcGIS 10.7) and want to change a polyline's point to another coordinates.
I know how to change it (move the point), but when I write like 56.3654275234542375 to set the X value, in ArcPy, the print() function only shows this X coordinate to 9 decimal places.

My questions are:

- Can the shapefile store the coordinates longer than 9 decimal places?
- How can I change the display length in ArcPy (or ArcGIS)?

Comment: Nine decimal places indicate an accuracy of `0.11 mm` or better. I strongly doubt your data is that accurate.

Comment: Specifying 18 significant digits is beyond the representation of IEEE 8-byte floating point ("double") representation, and well inside the measurable limit of subatomic structure, where matter can only be described by probablistic energy equations. ArcGIS libraries use 8-byte integer representation internally (even though shapefile stores doubles), so the SpatialReference will define the limits of coordinate representation (the default is far too precise for most geodata not collected with microscopes).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Vince!
I've just tested the limitations, because I needed to snap to another point, which has 37 decimal places, but now I'm going to think that those values are not real, just random numbers after 15 digits.

Comment: Unless you're using high-quality surveying equipment, the randomness is introduced after five or six digits, not fifteen.